# Performance overhead on Non-POT Texture in POT Atlas

Tags: unity, opengl, graphics, mobile

Using atlas, we can reduce memory and draw call. And the atlas is usally POT(Power of Two) Texture.

And I know non-POT texture have a lot of GPU and memory performance overhead. ([link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7927/why-would-you-use-textures-that-are-not-a-power-of-2))

I have many rendering objects and they have also their non-POT textures.
And I packed the images into one 1024*1024 POT atlas and applied them to the objects. 

(each textures is non-pot, and the atlas is pot texture)

In this case, Can I avoid non-pot texture overhead? 
Are they treated as non-pot texture or not internally?

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak specifically for Unity, as I don't use it, but based on my understanding of graphics hardware (I have written a multi-platform 2D rendering engine or two), there will be no performance overhead using non-pot sections of a pot texture.

I can think of no reason why this would be any different for Unity.  The overhead is purely hardware based.

Comment: Thanks Mick, many times, I heard that developer should use POT texture in Unity. especially in mobile for mipmapping overhead.